# realizar resta y que muestre los valores entre 1 y 10

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla la cual contiene

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta sentencia para que me de la resta de entradas menos salidas:

```
$sql="SELECT medicina_inventario,fecha_inventario,entrada_inventario,salida_inventario,total_inventario,inveObservaciones, entrada_inventario-salida_inventario total_inventario FROM tblinventario";
$resultado=$objConexion->query($sql);
```

Ahora necesito que muestre solo donde el total de la resta de entre 1 y 10

Yo maneje este pero no me da el resultado:

```
$sql="SELECT medicina_inventario,fecha_inventario,entrada_inventario,salida_inventario,total_inventario,inveObservaciones, entrada_inventario-salida_inventario AS total FROM tblinventario 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  AS total FROM tblinventario WHERE total='10'";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tus campos no son de agregacion (count, sum , avg, entr otros) puedes hacerlo en el where:

```
SELECT entrada_inventario-salida_inventario AS total 
  FROM tblinventario 
  WHERE (entrada_inventario-salida_inventario) >=1 
    and (entrada_inventario-salida_inventario)<=10
```

En caso que uses funciones de agregacion te recomiendo usar el [HAVING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) que seria un where dentro de la consulta ya finalizada y podemos usar el ALIAS  , asi evitarias el UNION

```
SELECT entrada_inventario-salida_inventario AS total 
  FROM tblinventario 
 having total >=1 and total <=10
```

Comment: muchas gracias a todos por su colaboración,  me sirvió mucho sus respuestas.

Comment: por favor lee de nuevo mi respuesta cometi un error en responderte con having, la consulta se demorara mucho menos unsando el where, si usas funciones como el count, sum avg alli si debes usar el having

Answer (score 2):

Te recomendaría que a tu `WHERE` le agregues el uso de `BETWEEN` para que indiques un **rango/intervalo** de valores que deseas obtener; de modo tal que también estarías estableciendo un límite de valores que deseas mostrar y descartando los demás

El primer valor que coloques es desde donde debe comenzar; en este caso 1, el segundo valor en este caso 10 es hasta donde debe terminar

**CÓDIGO**

```
$sql="SELECT medicina_inventario, fecha_inventario, entrada_inventario, 
             salida_inventario, total_inventario, inveObservaciones, 
             entrada_inventario-salida_inventario AS total 
      FROM tblinventario 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT AS total FROM tblinventario 
      WHERE total= BETWEEN 1 AND 10";
```

Comment: Si usa IN(1, 10) le va a devolver solo los resultados iguales a 1 o iguales a 10, no el rango. En este caso deberia usar el operador BETWEEN en vez de el IN.

Comment: me sigue saliendo error

Comment: si perdonen estaba con la idea de la funcionalidad de `BETWEEN` pero me equivoque y puse `IN`